# How harmful is it to expose access token to the resource owner?

Tags: oauth, facebook

While checking the facebook php sdk implementation I noticed that they expose the access token to the resource owner (user)

```
$params = array(
  'next' => $next,
  'access_token' => $session->getToken()
);
return 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?' . http_build_query($params, null, '&');
```

[FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L155](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/d620878b49a4bd7fd5ab609e023e92dc625b9316/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L155)

How harmful is it considered to be? I cannot explain it, but it just does not look right.

In case it's not "the best practice" how would one implement a logout using oauth v2 flow instead?

I have made some research in the specification and that's what I've found:

> Don't pass bearer tokens in page URLs:  Bearer tokens SHOULD NOT be
> passed in page URLs (for example, as query string parameters).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that bearer tokens and session tokens should not be passed int he url. The reasons are (according to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet)):

> might disclose the session ID (in web links and logs, web browser history and bookmarks, the Referer header or search engines)

In this specific case, I think Facebook did not care since the usage is logout - so after it has been called the token is not usable anymore any way, so no big deal if it is leaked.

Comment: "so after it has been called the token is not usable anymore" --- if only the logout process succeeded.

Comment: @zerkms you are right... I really don't understand why not stick to the safe behavior of not including the token in the URL also for the logout. I guess they wanted to simplify the logout action, or had it like this in legacy code...

Comment: Yep, the specification friendly and safe solution would require additional state: the temporary logout token. Which I suppose would be painful for a distributed system of a FB size